# R: How to avoid user input (or give the same input) in a loop

Tags: r, loops, input, user-input

I have a problem in one of my loops. Inside the loop, I am using a function that asks for user input in some cases. This function searches on a data base and when the object appears more than 1 time, it asks the user to choose among the multiple cases (function tax_rank() from the package taxize).

The basics would be:

```
species <- list("Ursus arctos", "Pica pica", "Cardamine nivalis")
for(sp in species){
    rank.taxa <- tax_rank(sp,db='gbif')
    if((is.na(rank.taxa))|rank.taxa!="species"){
     print("not a species")
    }else{
     print("species")
    }
```

If you try this, it should ask you for input in the case of Cardamine nivalis.

I have a lot of cases, so I wanted to modify my loop so it can automatically answer this question (e.g. choosing always the first case) or avoid giving input and either return a NA or an error.

Comment: Add a boolean logic check? Set it to 0 initially then at any time if you get to the case where you want to ignore certain stuff set it to 1. Just check the value of the bool and you can use this to skip certain sections of your loop.

Comment: How does it ask for input? The easiest method is probably to modify the function that asks for input to not ask for input instead

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow (SO). It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at the [_how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's also generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: @pablo-moreno-garcía sorry i missed this. `taxize` maintainer here. You can use the `rows` parameter `tax_rank(x="Cardamine nivalis", db = "gbif", rows = 1)` which is passed down to the `get_*` functions internally, which then only returns the row matching the `rows` value. HTH